# Use bs4 to scrape specific html table among several tables in same page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I want to scrape the last table titled `"Salaries"` on this website http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/alberma01.shtml

```
url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/alberma01.shtml'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
```

I've tried

```
div = soup.find('div', id='all_br-salaries')
```

and

```
div  = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'all_br-salaries'})
```

When I print `div` I see the data from the table but when I try something like:

```
div.find('thead')
div.find('tbody')
```

I get nothing.  My question is how can I select the table correctly so I can iterate over the tr/td & th tags to extract the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason? The HTML for that table is — don't ask me why — in a comment field. Therefore, dig the HTML out of the comment, turn *that* into soup and mine the soup in the usual way.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/alberma01.shtml').text
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> table_code = page[page.find('<table class="sortable stats_table" id="br-salaries"'):]
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(table_code, 'lxml')
>>> rows = soup.findAll('tr')
>>> len(rows)
14
>>> for row in rows[1:]:
...     row.text
...     
'200825Baltimore\xa0Orioles$395,000? '
'200926Baltimore\xa0Orioles$410,000? '
'201027Baltimore\xa0Orioles$680,0002.141 '
'201128Boston\xa0Red\xa0Sox$875,0003.141 '
'201229Boston\xa0Red\xa0Sox$1,075,0004.141contracts '
'201330Cleveland\xa0Indians$1,750,0005.141contracts '
'201431Houston\xa0Astros$2,250,0006.141contracts '
'201532Chicago\xa0White\xa0Sox$1,500,0007.141contracts '
'201532Houston\xa0Astros$200,000Buyout of contract option'
'201633Chicago\xa0White\xa0Sox$2,000,0008.141 '
'201734Chicago\xa0White\xa0Sox$250,000Buyout of contract option'
'2017 StatusSigned thru 2017, Earliest Free Agent: 2018'
'Career to date (may be incomplete)$11,385,000'
```

EDIT: I found that this was in a comment field by opening the HTML for the page in the Chrome browser and then look down through it for the desired table. This is what I found. Notice the opening `<!--`.

[image: HTML image]

Comment: What indicated it was in a comment field? And I understand that `table_code = page[page.find(<table class="sortable stats_table" id="br-salaries"'):]` is finding the correct table but why does it need to be a list before passing it to BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I've edited my answer for your first query. As to the second, that's not a list. That notation means a selection from a string. First I find where the table begins in the comment, then I select the part of the comment that begins with the beginning of the table.